# How do you use preventDefault() in React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native, preventdefault

I am using TextInput of `react-native-paper` on IOS. I want to use `preventDefault` for button `Enter`, `Tab`, `,` buttons but I can't find the `preventDefault` method for `react-native`. Is there a preventDefault method or any other way on react native for IOS?

```
  const handleKeyPress = ({nativeEvent: {key: keyValue}}: any) => {
    if (['Enter', 'Tab', ','].includes(keyValue)) {
    //want to use preventDefault here

    }
  };
```

```
 <TextInput
   keyboardType="email-address"
   mode="outlined"
   placeholder={t('Enter e-mail or several, split by comma')}
   value={email}
   onChangeText={onEmailChange}
   onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
   error={emailError}
   autoCapitalize="none"
 />
```